# Why do previews work in one browser, but not another?

Tags: admin-bar, previews, browser-compatibility

I keep having an intermittent issue where the admin bar disappears from a wordpress site I often use, when using my main browser (Google Chrome). I can access /wp-admin/ no problem, and another problem is that post previews will not work, instead showing me the 404 page.

Safari, however, works just fine. What can I do to get Chrome to behave properly again?

Comment: Disable all plugins and switch to Twenty Twelve. Does it still happen?

Comment: I can't do that, it's a production system

Comment: Luckily, you have an exact local dev copy of your site, so we don’t have to guess. :)

Comment: it doesn't happen at all with my dev copy. in fact, now it's mysteriously working again with the production version in chrome, despite having made no changes to plugins or themes whatsoever… I _know_ it must be something I'm doing but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the exact cause was, but [deleting cookies for the specific site](http://www.guidingtech.com/6295/delete-site-cookies-chrome/) fixed the problem.